# 404 redirection in htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess generated by a CMS. Whatever I do my 404 redirection does not lead to my custom 404 page

I do have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

and it seems to be working without this part of the file

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*).html$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=news [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=pages [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=category [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([^/]*)/$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$  $1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)_offset_([0-9]+))/$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=category&offset=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_show_all/$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=category&show_all=yes [L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?uri=$3&uriFor=product [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?uri=$2&uriFor=product [L]
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: I understand that. The question is how to fix it and not to break the integrity of the system. I am not very good in htaccess

Comment: What URL are you requesting that you would expect to 404? And what do you see exactly? Try requesting `/foo/bar/baz`. The point is, that if you are using a CMS then the 404 is likely controlled by the CMS, not by Apache. The pages in the CMS are not usually physical files on the filesystem.

Comment: user82217 - I thought of that first. But the CMS does not have such a functionality. It is a self written cms

Comment: I see a simple:  404 Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
how can I limit out this overwriting rule? How can I make the 404 page redirect to 404.html?

Comment: Comment out all the rules and see if `ErrorDocument 404` works or not. Once that works, start uncommenting each rewrite rule to see which one is causing problem.

Comment: done that. The error seems to be here: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([^/]*)/$ , But I thought the remaining part of the file might be useful.